# How can I run an mvc app on windows server?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I'm really new at this, never hosted an app before, everything I've done so far has been locally.

I have a windows server 2008 sp1 running at work, with IIS installed. I access to it via remote desktop, and I need to be able to deploy my app, first locally on the server, so computers that can access it (through LAN) are able to use it.

Right now, if I create a folder and put some data in it, with an html file, and go to "localhost" in a browser, I can see the rendered html file.

The version installed is IIS 7.0, and my app is uses the MVC pattern, and .net framework 4.6.

If on my windows 10 PC I start my app (vs 2017) I can see it on my browser.

I want to be able to do what I do in my PC but on the server. How can I do this?

Update:

I tried Publishing the app through vs but that is on my windows pc and getting a lot of errors. What I know so far is that a guy from Networks gets the app by the developers and they publish it, but I don't know what kind of files does he need.

I followed tutorials but I just can't apply them.

As I said earlier, I have visual studio installed on my w10 PC, and tried publishing through that app to the ip where the server is, getting a lot of errors.

I don't know what to do, I'm really trying a lot of different things, but I don't even know how the app is supposed to look to be run in any way that is not how I run it in visual studio.

***UPDATE:***

I'm getting this error when I try to publish locally
[image]

Comment: You either need to have same version of Net Library installed on server (as build PC) or Publish application and then run the SETUP.EXE that is generated by the publish to Disk.

Comment: as mentioned - you'll need .NET on the server. You don't necessarily need MVC installed on there as well as you can 'bin deploy' the dll files needed (look that up). The site will need to be set up in IIS with an `Integrated` app pool. Also, you may need to install the URL Rewrite module on the server too.

Comment: 1. You need to publish the App, you can do that from VS2017 itself
2. Go to IIS console and configure a new instance and point that to the path where you deployed the app, you can also specify the port where you want to host the app 

3. Finally Allow incoming traffic on the port

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a number of ways to deploy to IIS. One option is too publish from Visual Studio to a folder and copy that to the server, it depends on your requirements.

Comment: @RyanThomas I just edited and explained what I tried so far

Comment: @Clint I tried that trying to point to the server, I just realized that I should just do it locally and copy the generated files to the server... I don't know if it will work, but I will try that now and will update my question

Comment: @newbie, yea there are so many ways to do this, and tons of articles and tons of ways to get it wrong :D
I once had to host .net core app on my Win10 pc and had it deployed on xx Port and others were able to access this. 
If you can open a chat discussion, I can help

Comment: Thanks @Clint, never created a chat room... until now
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204491/trying-to-host-an-app

Comment: Hi @newbie ,
Did the approach help answer your question regarding "Trying to host an app"
If yes please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This will also help others understand you've found a solution.

Comment: @Clint it kinda did. Even though I was about to watch that video (I really like Tim corey videos) and I had to do much more to make it work it helped. Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Outline of what we need as per OPs requirement

> 1. In VS publish the App to a folder
> 2. Sort out the server prerequisites:
>
>    - Turning Windows Feature On or Off for ASP.NET, ISAPI filters, ISAPI extensions, NET extensibility
>    - Server should have .NetFramework installed
> 3. Copy the published folder to the Server
> 4. Configure IIS manager to add a new site and set physical path to published folder